# Crystal Report Not showing any data from Dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have been using Crystal reports from a long time. I had been developing an inventory system in windows forms.

Since I have to get data from different tables in Crystal reports, so i have made custom data set filled it with my required rows as follows:

**Code:**

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter myDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
CustomDataSet myDS = new CustomDataSet();

con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
cmd.Connection = con;

//receipt code goes here
                string query = "select Customer.CustomerName as Name,Customer.Address as Address,Customer.ContactNo as ContactNo, Product.ProductName as ItemName, ProductSold.Quantity as Quantity, Invoice_Info.InvoiceNo as InvoiceNumber, ProductSold.Price as PriceOfItem, ProductSold.Tax as TaxOnItem, ProductSold.Discount as DiscountOnItem, Invoice_Info.TotalPayment as PaidAmount, Invoice_Info.SoldBy as Salesman, Invoice_Info.CashedBy as Cashier, Invoice_Info.DiscountAmount as DiscountOnInvoice, Invoice_Info.PaymentType as PaymentType from Invoice_Info,Product,ProductSold,Customer where Invoice_Info.CustomerID=Customer.CustomerId and Invoice_Info.InvoiceNo=ProductSold.InvoiceNo and ProductSold.ProductID=Product.ProductId and Invoice_Info.InvoiceNo=" + txtInvoiceNo.Text;
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
myDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
myDA.Fill(myDS.Invoice);

//if customer is walking customer show change else show credit of regular customer
if (txtCustomerName.Text == Constants.WalkingCustomer)
{
for (int i = 0; i < myDS.Invoice.Count; i++)
{
myDS.Invoice[i].Balance = double.Parse(txtTotal.Text) - double.Parse(txtTotalPayment.Text);
}
}

//filling company informtation
myDS.Company.AddCompanyRow(Company.Name, Company.Address, Company.Phone);
rptReceipt rpt = new rptReceipt();
rpt.SetDataSource(myDS);
frmInvoiceReport frm = new frmInvoiceReport();
frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
frm.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
frm.Visible = true;
```

**Image of CR designed report:**

[image]

**Image of Custom Dataset:**

[image]

**Dataset filled image**

[image]

**Empty report**

[image]

**Question:**
Since everything is perfect. Why my data does not show on report?

Comment: are you getting any error message? Does the DataType from your Database and DataTable Match?

Comment: The dataType  perfectly matches. Nothing is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with data not displaying at all.

Assuming you already have your dataSet filled with your data just sent your datatable to your report like that :

```
        rptH.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(myDataTableCompany);
        rptH.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(myInvoiceDataTable);
```

Check the order of your report Tables in the debug menu, set it like this and it will be ok. ( or change the order if CR wants an other order )

Comment: I did this thing
`rpt.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource((System.Data.DataTable)myDS.Company);
                rpt.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource((System.Data.DataTable)myDS.Invoice);`

Comment: Did you check that you have some rows in your datatables before the binding ? Close the connection before setting the datasource and after filling  the dataset and try

Comment: yes i showed them in debugged window in image in my question!

Answer (score 0):

For Name, Address, Phone No Use TextObjects(Crystal Reports Text Field) instead of DataTable and use it as

```
    rptReciept reciept = new rptReciept();

    TextObject tName = (TextObject)reciept.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtName"];
    TextObject tAddress = (TextObject)reciept.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtAddress"];
    TextObject tPhone = (TextObject)reciept.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtPhoenNo"];
```

Considering you have fetched the data from DB rSelect is the resultSet

```
    tName.Text = rSelect.Table["c_name"].ToString();
    tAddress.Text = rSelect.Table["c_address"].ToString();
    tPhone.Text = rSelect.Table["c_phone"].ToString();
```

For Invoice alone DataSet With single INVOICE DataTable and try the Below Code Where rSelect is the ResultSet of Invoice

```
    CustomDataSet dsInvoice = new CustomDataSet();
    DataTable tblInvoice = rSelect.ResultSet;
    tblInvoice.TableName = "tblInvoice"; // The TableName which you used while creating the DataTable in DataSet.
    dsInvoice.Merge(tblInvoice);
```

The below code is to display a form with CrystalReportViewer crv

```
    frmShowReport frm = new frmShowReport();
    frm.Show();
    reciept.SetDataSource(tblInvoice);
    frm.crv.ReportSource = reciept;
    frm.crv.Show();
```

Comment: It throws indexOutOfBound exception: 
`              ((TextObject)rpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtCompanyName"]).Text = Company.Name;
`

Comment: Have you inserted TextField in CrystalReports instead of DataField

Comment: yes i added TextObject in crystal report, set it's name to "txtCompanyName" and then set according to the code.

Comment: it will throw exception only when there is no such field present in the crystal report.

Comment: the field is there, i used exact name! and neither second part of your solution worked for invoice.

Comment: can you post your exact exception

Comment: Problem is that i am not getting any exception. and data is not being shown in Report.

Comment: It throws indexOutOfBound exception:  then how come you got this?

Comment: In case if i use the code you provided. 
 
yes i added TextObject in crystal report, set it's name to "txtCompanyName" and then set according to the code.

Comment: in case if i use my code i don't get exception. Datatable in DataSet is filled accurately, but the data does not displays in Crystal reports

Comment: Fine what is happening now? Can u pls brief it and also brief what you are expecting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128715/discussion-between-prashanth-and-umar).